# Possible to backout a Perforce integration that branched a deleted file?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I discovered that some old branch integrations in Perforce re-created some files that were previously deleted. Because this was not caught in time, later integrations also modified the branched file.

For example:

```
        MAIN         BRANCH
cl 1: X rev#1  ==  X rev#1
cl 2:              X removed in branch
cl 3: X rev#2
cl 4:              main -> branch integration, X#2 reappears
cl 5: X rev#3
cl 6:              main -> branch integration, X rev#3
```

What is the "Perforce" way to back out these changes. Clearly, I could go in and delete file `X` in BRANCH and submit that. However, if it were 100s of files, this would be quite a task.

The more correct path, would seem to be to back out the integration of the file. However, I attempted this, and Perforce does not actually mark the file to be deleted.

Its not clear if you should backout change list 6, or change list 4?

Is this a perforce or user bug? Maybe there is some flag to force perforce to remove files during a "back out" operation.

Comment: How did change 4 not trigger a conflict when doing `p4 resolve`?  Or were you using `p4 integrate -Dt`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd back out changelist #4.  There's no fully automated way to fix this.  You could probably write a script that takes care of most of the grunt work.  In the future you should use a branch spec to tell Perforce to ignore file 'X' in all future merges.

Comment: So every time someone deletes/moves a file the branch spec has to reflect that? I don't see how that would scale to a large project.